# How to extract elements in lists of a list

Tags: python

I have randomly generated a list that looks something like

```
ls = [[0.0, 1, ['B']], [0.0625, 1, ['C']], [0.125, 1, ['B']], [0.1875, 1, ['A']], [0.25, 1, ['F']], [0.3125, 1, ['D']]]
```

Does anyone know how I can extract all the third element in the nested list (i.e. all the letters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_list = [element[2][0] for element in ls]
```

This should work